# Python – exec not interpreting string variable

Tags: python, string, exec

I've been really frustrated with an error I keep getting, no matter what I attempt. I'm trying to make variables out of a list words from a file and set them to an empty string (for later use).

Here's the code snippet:

```
values = []
input_values = open('list.txt')
for i in input_values.readlines():
    i = i.strip("\n")
    values.append(str(i))
for i in values:
    exec(str(i) + " = ''")
```

And here's the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 59, in <module>
    exec(str(i) + " = ''")
  File "<string>", line 2
    = ''
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I've also tried without using `for i in values` but still got the same output. And what strange is that I can print the value, but not use it. If I add `print i` after the `strip()` line, then `line1` gets added to the top of the output.

So this:

```
values = []
input_values = open('list.txt')
for i in input_values.readlines():
    i = i.strip("\n")
    print i
    values.append(str(i))
    exec(str(i) + " = ''")
```

Yields this:

```
line1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 59, in <module>
    exec(str(i) + " = ''")
  File "<string>", line 2
    = ''
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? I suspect that what you really need is a `dict`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm making a script, emulating **msfconsole** from the [Metasploit Framework](https://www.metasploit.com). Variables need setting, resetting, sending as command line arguments when executing outside scripts, etc.

Comment: Have you got a blank line in your input file ?

Comment: @CMDej No, there are no blank lines.

Comment: Yes there is a blank line, at the *end* of the file, with a space.

Comment: Also do not use `readlines` if all you do is iterate over the lines of a file (`for i in input_values:`)

Comment: Can you post the input file?

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one empty line at the end of your file, with a space, which causes the error. You'd want to `strip` the whitespace out of all lines and then check if they're empty, before appending them to the list:

```
values = []
input_values = open('list.txt')
for i in input_values.readlines():
    i = i.strip()
    if i:
        values.append(str(i))
for i in values:
    exec(str(i) + " = ''")
```

Also, the `.readlines` is unnecessary, `values` is unnecessary and even `exec` is completely unnecessary - instead you could use this:

```
with open('list.txt') as input_values:
    for i in input_values:
        i = i.strip()
        if i:
            globals()[i] = ''
```

though it wouldn't complain if you tried to set a variable named `5` for example